# circle detection from a unknown drawing

Tags: java, detection, geometry

I am working on a system which can draw node and edge graphs. I am using Java canvas so I can get the user to free hand draw everything they want on the program. Is there an algorithm out there which can check the array list of points which I get from this, to check if the line is closer to a circle or a line? currently I'm just checking if any points (other than itself) are equal to the same point to classify a circle. I'm sure there are better ways of detecting a circle. any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to track user drawing-moves? Or you're have access only to canvas?

Comment: as the user click and drags the mouse, I am saving the x and y value of the mouse and adding it to the arraylist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general tip - **use vectors and angles for classification, instead of individual points**. This is technique, on which many interactive text recognition systems are based.

In your case, closed figures with higher probability are circles.

So, if you can track continuous drawing-moves of user, just push each vector of drawing-move to stack.

Afterwards, all you need - just calculate sum of angles between vectors from stack (note, that sign of angle depends on sign of [pseudoscalar product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)). If sum is nearly `pi` - it means, that figure is a circle, otherwise - line

**P.S.** Tip to track **continuous drawing-moves** - just calculate **delay** between sequential drags and clicks

[image]